# Text selection toolbar not visible in pre marshmallow versions without ActionBar

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

On marshmallow, i can see the Floating Toolbar for TextView with custom actions but prior to marshmallow i can't see the toolbar because my activity doesn't extend AppCompatActivity or there is no ActionBar. How can i fix?

I'm sort of looking for something similar for TextView- 
[Is it possible to create a custom floating text selection menu in Android versions pre Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330625/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-floating-text-selection-menu-in-android-versio)